# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<EquipChangeNotifier> above this EquipmentItemWidget$ Widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview, provider

I am new to flutter (I am an android developer) and I have a problem that I do not have the solution to. 
## What i'm looking to do ## 
I want to create a horizontal list view with stateful widgets as an item. These items can be selected or deselected. They are part of a page.
[list view item selected][1]
[list view item not selected][2]

### The error

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this EquipmentItemWidget$ Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that EquipmentItemWidget$ is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
  ```

### My code

#### SearchGamePage.dart

```
class SearchGamePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchGamePageState createState() => _SearchGamePageState();
}

class _SearchGamePageState extends State<SearchGamePage> {
  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            buttonSearch,
            inputBarSearch,
            sliderNumberPerson,
            listEquipment,
            sliderHardness
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

#### EquipChangeNotifier.dart

```
class EquipChangeNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  bool isEquip;

  EquipChangeNotifier(this.isEquip);

  //GETTER
  bool get isEquipGet => isEquip;
  //SETTER
  set isEquipSet(bool isEquip){
    this.isEquip = isEquip;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

#### EquipmentItemWidget.dart

```
class EquipmentItemWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  final String type;

  EquipmentItemWidget({Key key, this.type}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EquipmentItemWidgetState createState() => _EquipmentItemWidgetState(type);
}

class _EquipmentItemWidgetState extends State<EquipmentItemWidget> {

  bool isSelected = false;
  final type;

  final List<String> urlIconEquipment = ['images/equipment/balle_ping_pong.PNG', 'images/equipment/carte.PNG', 'images/equipment/des.PNG', 'images/equipment/goblet.PNG', 'images/equipment/table.PNG'];

  _EquipmentItemWidgetState(this.type);

  String getPath(String type){
    switch(type){
      case 'balle':
        return urlIconEquipment[0];
      case 'carte':
        return urlIconEquipment[1];
      case 'des':
        return urlIconEquipment[2];
      case 'goblet':
        return urlIconEquipment[3];
      case 'table':
        return urlIconEquipment[4];
    }
  }

  void _toggleEquipmentSearch(EquipChangeNotifier notifier){
    setState(() {
      isSelected = !isSelected;
      notifier.isEquipSet = isSelected;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    EquipChangeNotifier notifier = Provider.of<EquipChangeNotifier>(context);
    isSelected = notifier.isEquipGet;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        _toggleEquipmentSearch(notifier);
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(300),
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  color: Colors.white24,
                  child: (Image.asset(
                      (!isSelected?getPath(type):'images/equipment/valid.PNG'),
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                  )),
                )),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                child: Text(type, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Thank you in advance for your help !!

Comment: where are you instantiating the `EquipChangeNotifier`? where is your provider/multiProvider/... widget?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! my goal is to create a list of (identical) widgets with each a different provider to be able to select each widget independently. I have advanced a bit, and now I have no more errors, but when I click on an item (Widget) all the other items also select because it shares the same provider ... I don't really know how do apart create several different Provider but that annoys me because the items are the same.

Comment: I instantiate the provider in SearchGamePage :                                                     
 `return ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_)=> EquipChangeNotifier(isEquip: false),
        child: pageSearchWidget);`

Comment: And i have access of my provider in EquipmentItemWidget (which is instantiated several times) by : `Provider.of<EquipChangeNotifier>(context).isEquip`